# How might I output duplicates from six tab-delimited files only if they are duplicated across all of those files?

Tags: duplicates

I'm rather new to Linux and programming and would love a bit of help with managing duplicates, please. I've been fiddling around with uniq, join, diff, grep and have found a few forum posts that almost answer my question, but not quite.

I have six very large tab-delimited .txt files (approx 26000 lines each), which are similar but not identical. I want to somehow create a script that will examine the contents of all six files, and only output the lines that appear in every single one of these six files, to a new file.

Thank you very much!

*edit The problem I'm having is that diff/comm etc are no good for more than two or three files, and uniq also seems to only output uniq lines not duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

For sorted input files named f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6 this should produce the output you are looking for:

```
comm -12 f5 f6 | comm -12 f4 - | comm -12 f3 - | comm -12 f2 - | comm -12 f1 - > output
```

The - in the chained comm commands takes the output of the previous as its input.